# Angular 9 - how to merge 2 http.get into one Observable

Tags: angular

I use Angular 9 and want to merge 2 results from backend into one. My current method:

```
protected getDataSource(): Observable<AgentSummary> | Refresher<any, AgentSummary> {
  return this.groupSelector.selectedGroup$.pipe(e =>
    filter(Boolean),
    switchMap((group: SelectedGroup) => this.dashboardHttp.getAgentsStatus(group.id))
  );
}
```

I want to invoke additional http.get and merge it with

```
switchMap((group: SelectedGroup) => this.dashboardHttp.getAgentsStatus(group.id))

:

getRecoveryPoints(groupId: string): Observable<BackupSummary> {
  const headers: HttpHeaders = getHeaders(groupId);

    return this.http.get<BackupSummary>(`${this.env.URI}/backup/api/v1/dashboard/recovery-point`, {
    headers: headers,
  });
}
```

How to do that? I'm new in Angular so please be understanding for me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the rxjs function `combineLatest` should be what you need, you can read more about it [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) .

```
combineLatest([
  this.getDataSource(),
  this.getRecoveryPoints(groupId)
]).subscribe(([dataSource, recoveryPoints]) => {
  // do something
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For combining two rest call you use `combineLatest` from `rxjs`

Example:

```
combineLatest([
   this.dashboardHttp.firstCall(),
   this.dashboardHttp.secondCall()
]).subscribe(([firstCallResponse, secondCallResponse]) => {
   console.log(firstCallResponse);
   console.log(secondCallResponse);
});
```

This way you can combine two call from backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine http calls or any other kind of `observables` in many ways, my favorite is using `combineLatest`, [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) is the documentation:

```
let getDataSource$ = getDataSource();
let getRecoveryPoints$ = getRecoveryPoints();

combineLatest(getDataSource$, getRecoveryPoints$, 
  (dataSource, recoveryPoints) => ({dataSource, recoveryPoints})
    .subscribe( results => {
       let ( dataSource, recoveryPoints) = result;
         ... // do your stuff with the results
    })
```